# Grabbing Percentages Off Of Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to grab the percentage of 100% and turn it into a whole number of 100. Whenever I try to grab it, it grabs the value 1. I'm grabbing the data from a sheet using the with function. I'm grabbing from a cell whos value is 100% and is a percentage formatted cell.

I've tried to use .Value and .Text and scanned them into String and Integer at the same time to see if I can get 100 or at least 100%, but it just keeps giving me 1

```
Sub GrabPercentage()
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Configuration Values")          
        Dim TestString As String
        Dim TestInteger As Integer
        TestString = .Cells(ConfigCounter, 17)
        TestInteger = .Cells(ConfigCounter, 17)

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: But 100% = 1. You'll have to multiply by 100, right?

Comment: `TestInteger = .Cells(ConfigCounter, 17) * 100`

Comment: Yikes that's embarrassing, thank you both for pointing that out so fast.

Comment: Ha, we've all had those days :)